# How can i send data to markdown laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I'm using laravel notification for send verification email to users.

This is my `toMail` function in `VerifyEmailNotification` :

```
public function toMail($notifiable)
{
    $verificationUrl = $this->verificationUrl($notifiable);

    if (static::$toMailCallback) {
        return call_user_func(static::$toMailCallback, $notifiable, $verificationUrl);
    }

    return (new MailMessage)
        ->subject('Verification Email')
        ->markdown('emails.verify-email', ['url' => $verificationUrl]);
}
```

And this is my markdown view :

```
@component('mail::message')

<p>Verification link : </p>

@component('mail::button',['url' => $verificationUrl])
    Verify
@endcomponent

<p>{{ env('APP_NAME') }}</p>

@endcomponent
```

As you can see i pass `$verificationUrl` to Markdown view, But when i click on send verificaion link, i got this error :

```
Undefined variable: verificationUrl (View: D:\Web\projects\pi\resources\views\emails\verify- 
email.blade.php)
```

Why i have this error and what can i do ?

Comment: You called your variable `url` and not `verificationUrl` here: `->markdown('emails.verify-email', ['url' => $verificationUrl])`. So you have to use `$url` in the view.

Comment: yes, Thank you :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you passed variable $verificationUrl to markdown and named it url so you should access it by calling $url not $verificationUrl

```
markdown('emails.verify-email', ['url' => $verificationUrl]);
```